# X-axis duplicates for a time series using facet_wrap in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, facet-wrap

I hope you are having a nice day! So, I have a large dataset for around twenty years that I'm trying to use the facet_wrap argument to visualize it all. Here's a simplified version of the data for troubleshooting purposes:

```
data <- data.frame(
Date = c("1993-06-09", "1993-08-16", "1993-09-13", "1993-10-11", "1993-11-08", "1994-03-06", "1994-05-20", "1994-07-12", "1994-12-06", "1994-09-07", "1995-04-04", "1995-01-07", "1995-02-06"),
Oxygen = c("15", "15.8", "15.3", "16", "16", "14.5", "14.9", "15.2", "15.7", "15", "12.6", "12.8", "13.5"),
Year = c("1993", "1993", "1993", "1993", "1993", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1994", "1995", "1995", "1995"),
Month = c("6", "8", "9", "10", "11", "3", "5", "7", "12", "9", "4", "1", "2"),
Day = c("9", "16", "13", "11", "8", "6", "20", "12", "6", "7", "4", "7", "6")
)
```

Here's the rest of the code around it:

```
data$Oxygen <- as.numeric(as.character(data$Oxygen))
data$Year <- as.numeric(as.character(data$Year))
data$Month <- as.numeric(as.character(data$Month))
data$Day <- as.numeric(as.character(data$Day))
data$Date <- as.Date(data$Date)
ggplot(data = data, aes(x=Date, y=Oxygen)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "loess", se=FALSE) + facet_wrap( ~ Year, ncol=2) + scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%B")  + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

The code creates this graph:

[image: img]

My problem is with the x-axis. How do I change it so that it isn't creating a continuous series of months for each year after one another? I want it so that it all fits under the months for a single year and not creating more months as if each year is different.

This is what it looks like when I put in the rest of the years:

[image: img]

It's plotting each year's x-axis instead of just the single year's worth of months.

Lastly, how do I tell ggplot that I want to see the week or day within each month, so that not all the points are just centered on a fixed spot for that month along the x-axis.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: the option `facet_wrap( ~ Year, ncol=2, scales = "free_x")` is one option - it will just show the months with data

Comment: Unfortunately, @MelissaKey I've tried the `scales = "free_x"` option and it doesn't quite work. You are right that it just shows months with the data, but I want all the months, even if there aren't values for corresponding months there for certain years, to be present--just not duplicated for however many years are available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get consistent month breaks, you can make a dummy variable of dates, all with the same year, and facet by the actual years. That way, you still have a date on the x-axis, giving you access to `scale_x_date`, but can split the data neatly by year.

I did the cleanup with `dplyr`, both for conciseness and preference, and made a dummy date column where I changed the year to 2018, then converted to a date object with `lubridate::ymd`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

data2 <- data %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-Date), function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))) %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
  mutate(dummy_date = paste("2018", Month, Day) %>% ymd())


ggplot(data2, aes(x = dummy_date, y = Oxygen, group = Year)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = loess, se = FALSE) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%B") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Year, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-06-25 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: (restated from comments) - use `facet_wrap` to only display the relevant window of time.

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x=Month, y=Oxygen)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", se=FALSE) + 
  facet_wrap( ~ Year, ncol=2, scales = 'free_x') + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%B")  + 
  theme(
    axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")
  )
```

Option2: use `Month` as the x-axis:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x=Month, y=Oxygen)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", se=FALSE) + 
  facet_wrap( ~ Year, ncol=2) + 
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Date", breaks = 1:12, labels = month.name) + 
  # scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%B")  + 
  theme(
    axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")
  )
```

I don't work much with dates, so this is a hack - but its probably good enough until/unless someone shows a good solution.

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x=Month + pmin(Day/30, 1), y=Oxygen)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", se=FALSE) + 
  facet_wrap( ~ Year, ncol=2) + 
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Date", breaks = 1:12, labels = month.name) + 
  # scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%B")  + 
  theme(
    axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")
  )
```

Comment: Is there some modification available in ggplot for option 2, so that the points aren't solidly just on the month instead of somewhere in between to suggest a time in the month? Right now, the data points suggest that it all takes place on the first day of every month.